# Getting error in function with calculation function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, error-handling, calculator

I'm currently creating a macro calculator but I'm getting an error with the actual calculation function. The error I'm getting is 'Missing initializer in const declaration'.

```
const [weight,setWeight] = useState("");
const [height, setHeight] = useState("");
const [age, setAge] = useState("");
const [activityLevel, setActivityLevel] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}

const calculateMacros(weight,height,age,activityLevel) => {
    const BMR = 10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age;

    let TDEE = 0;

    switch(activityLevel) {
        case 'sedentary':
            TDEE = BMR * 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Umm...
I think this part is incorrect.

```
const calculateMacros(weight,height,age,activityLevel) => {...}
```

This must be like below code:

```
const calculateMacros = (weight,height,age,activityLevel) => {...}
```